# (make) Recipes breaks after definding PATH

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, gnu-toolchain

I am trying to automate the building of my toolchain, however every time I set my PATH using a recipe, it breaks the future recipes to ignore the prefix of `@` and passes all commands after that directory from shell.

Here is one of my constructs:

```
%-build-glibc:
    @echo "Building glibc"
    @mkdir -p $(DIR_BUILD)/glibc
    @export PATH=$(PATH):$(DIR_INSTALL)/bin && \
    @cd $(DIR_BUILD)/glibc && \
    $(call cmd,$(DIR_BUILD)/glibc-$(VER_GLIBC)/configure \
      --host=$(TARGET_MACH) \
      --prefix=/usr \
      --libdir=/usr/lib \
      --with-headers=$(DIR_SYSROOT)/usr/include \
      --enable-bind-now \
      --enable-kernel=$(VER_LINUX) \
      --enable-stack-protector=strong \
      --disable-profile \
      --disable-werror \
      libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes \
      libc_cv_ctors_header=yes \
      libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes \
      libc_cv_slibdir=/lib \
      CFLAGS="-O2") && \
    $(call cmd,make -k install-headers cross_compiling=yes install_root=$(DIR_SYSROOT)) && \
    $(call cmd,make -j8) && \
    $(call cmd,make install install_root=$(DIR_SYSROOT))
```

And here is the output:

```
Building glibc

/bin/sh: 2: @cd: not found

make: *** [Rules.mk:166: aarch64-build-glibc] Error 1
```

I've tried echoing the result of PATH to see if it somehow just broke PATH itself, however once I get to that stage itself its like the whole shell doesn't work.

Comment: When you say "using Recipe Echo", I guess you mean prefixing the command with `@`.  That's confusing.  "Recipe echo" is how the `make` manual describes the *standard behavior* of echoing commands to stdout before executing them.  Prefixing with `@` suppresses that behavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry for the confusion, I wrote the initial post with a whole bunch of echos trying to figure out what went wrong with PATH and why it was breaking. After setting PATH ```make``` chooses to ignore the ```@``` prefix as a prefix and pushes that to shell as well. so of course the error ```@cd: not found``` is not going to be found, but I can't seem to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `@` to suppress command echoing is an aspect of `make` syntax that operates on a per-logical-line basis.  It is not a shell feature, and `make` does not attribute special significance to `@` other than at the beginning of a logical line.

I interpret the question as saying that you inserted

> ```
>     @export PATH=$(PATH):$(DIR_INSTALL)/bin && \
> ```

before the following *physical* line:

> ```
>     @cd $(DIR_BUILD)/glibc && \
> ```

.  But that backslash (`\`) at the end is a line-continuation marker, indicating that the next physical line is part of the same logical line.  You need that in this case.  But it means that the `cd` does not appear at the start of a logical line, so `make` does nothing with the `@` preceding it.  As a result, the shell is trying to execute a command named `@cd`, which does not exist.

Note how none of the physical lines following the `cd` have `@` prefixes.  Since the `cd` no longer appears at the beginning of a logical line, you want it to be like all the subsequent lines, without an `@`:

```
%-build-glibc:
    @echo "Building glibc"
    @mkdir -p $(DIR_BUILD)/glibc
    @export PATH=$(PATH):$(DIR_INSTALL)/bin && \
      cd $(DIR_BUILD)/glibc && \
      $(call cmd,$(DIR_BUILD)/glibc-$(VER_GLIBC)/configure \
      ...
```